# ANOVA failed to model data, what is a more appropriate test?

Tags: r, anova, statistical-significance

This is a cross-post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432964/anova-error-in-levelsxx) about an error I received in R while trying to run an ANOVA on my data. But error aside, I need help understanding why an ANOVA can't deal with my data and what other statistical models could be applied instead.

So here's my objective: I have 3 people (speaker) who recorded a bunch of words that I analyzed. The analysis yielded 3 continuous variables: skewness, kurtosis and Center of Gravity (CoG)*. I need to find out what combinations of these 3 variables best model the difference between each speaker. For example, are skewness and CoG together more significant than just CoG in finding the difference between speakers?

I have a basic knowledge of stats, but erring on the side of assuming I'm an idiot might be better for any complex explanations.

Thanks in advance!

- The skewness is a measure for how much the shape of the spectrum below the center of gravity is different from the shape above the mean frequency.
- The kurtosis is a measure for how much the shape of the spectrum around the center of gravity is different from a Gaussian shape.
- The center of gravity is a measure for how high the frequencies in a spectrum are on average weighted by their energy.

Comment: You should always include a sample of your data, the exact commands you ran, and the exact error you got. Otherwise it is hard to know what you did (or what you did wrong). NVM - I see you posted the info in the other post.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed everyone would look at the other post. I should probably have posted it here anyway. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: CoG? Could you please expand your abbreviation in-question?

Comment: Center of Gravity. It's measure of where the greatest energy concentration occurs over a given frequency in speech.

Comment: As I already asked please clarify *in the question*. That is, please edit your question to make the question clear (and even better, fully define 'center of gravity'). Hardly any of us are speech researchers, and not everyone reads all the comments in order to understand the questions, which should stand alone.

Comment: @Glen_b Well you don't need to be a speech researcher to know the difference between _in question_ and _in the question_... Hehe, but jokes aside, I will clarify my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to do Multinomial regression. Perhaps look up information on that.

Here is a great start:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm

e.g.

```
install.packages('nnet')
library(nnet)

test<-multinom(formula = as.factor(speaker) ~ CoG * skewness * kurtosis, data = total)


z <- summary(test)$coefficients/summary(test)$standard.errors
# 2-tailed z test
p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2
```

Comment: How did the continuous variables became discrete (multinomial)?

Comment: I thought she said speaker was discrete (1,2,or 3)

Comment: Ah, I get it. You're reading it as "who is speaking" is the response? I didn't read it like that.

Comment: Just to clarify, the end result ('p' in this case) is going to be a list of p-values for each level, right?

Comment: Also, this leads to another question: So if we know that CoG and Kurtosis are significant in predicting differences between speakers, does this also mean that there is significant difference between speakers based on these variables?

Comment: @Shakesbeery it is important to note that multinomial regression fits pairwise models (like speaker 3 compared to speaker 1, speaker 2 compared to speaker 1) I highly recommend going through the examples on the link I provided to gain a greater understanding of the output.

Comment: @Benjamin I see from a clarification on the identical question posted to reddit that the OP does appear to intend it the way you interpret it. My apologies.

Comment: @Glen_b man...this is probably first time that I have been correct and a mod has been wrong. My life has gotten so much better!

Comment: Sorry, but that's still to come -- I'm not a mod.